# How do I disable selecting line in a word processor

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, word-processing

I have a document with lots of line to be edited and want to disable selecting the line when I click empty left part of it. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Word screenshot]

I tried Notepad++, Notepad, MS Word, Wordpad, Dremweaver however couldn't do what I want and find that kind of option.

**EDIT:** I'm trying to join thousands of lines in a text file (but not all of them) manually.

Here's a part of the text:

The campaign brought honours and promotion 
to many, but for me it had nothing but misfortune 
and disaster. I was removed from my brigade and 
attached to the Berkshires, with whom I served at the 
fatal battle of Maiwand. There I was struck on the 
shoulder by a Jezail bullet, which shattered the bone 
and grazed the subclavian artery. I should have fallen ...

I want to convert it to:

> The campaign brought honours and promotion to many, but for me it had
>   nothing but misfortune and disaster. I was removed from my brigade and
>   attached to the Berkshires, with whom I served at the fatal battle of
>   Maiwand. There I was struck on the shoulder by a Jezail bullet, which
>   shattered the bone and grazed the subclavian artery. I should have
>   fallen ...

Comment: In notepad++ clicking in empty space in any line does **not** select it. It **highlights** the current line (which is not the same thing as a selection). Note that moving the cursor between lines with up or down arrow shows exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Yeah I know the blue mark indicates that the cursor is inside that line. The first thing I tried was using keyboard arrows. However there are thousands of lines I need to edit (bringing one line to above, but not all). So endkey+rightarrow+backspace isn't what I want.  I just wanted to get rid of this nonsense select action and use mouseclick+backspace combination. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are actually trying to achieve. If you can clarify your problem we may be able to help.

Comment: oh, I'm trying to move each line to its above, manually.

Comment: You want to join the lines together? Or select a line and move it one line up and the line above down?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with some sample text and show before and after?

Comment: yes I want to join them. I saved a PDF file as a text and the lines are half. Sorry for my English.

Comment: See my notepad solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I join lines in Notepad++?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\r\n`
- Set "Replace with" to (empty string)
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Find next"
- Click "Replace" to change the matching EOL or click "Find next" to skip to the next match.
- Repeat as necessary.

  [image]

**Before**:

```
1st line 
2nd line 
3rd line
```

**After**:

```
1st line 2nd line 3rd line
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: I'm still caring about line selection issue however thanks for this easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Word, you have to click very close the beginning of the line to select it. If you select next to line, but not close, it will not select it and drop any previous selections.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I know it, I wondered if there's a solution that I stated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at "Word Options", clicking "Advanced" and then under "Editing options", clear the "When selecting, automatically select entire word check box"? There may be additional options you can review in this location as well.

Comment: I just tried what you told. I give up, DavidPostill's solution works fine.

Comment: Now that you've explained what you're trying to do, using find and replace all to eliminate all the line returns makes sense, as Davis described. Giving more information up front is always helpful. Glad you got it fixed.